# angular2 work with Observable(Http) without reloading

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, rxjs

I have a PartnersService that in constructor load list of partners array from server.

```
this.partners = this._http.get('/app/partners/partners.data.json')
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
```

When I get a list of partners, everything OK.
But I need to get partner by ID.
In this case, I use function with callback

```
getPartner(id:number, callback:(partner:Partner)=>void):void {
    this.partners.subscribe(partners=> {
        for (let partner of partners) {
            if (partner.id == id) {
                callback(partner);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In browser console, I see that any time when I call `subscribe`, angular2 send request to server. Can I do something, to not send request any time? And maybe exist better way to create `getPartner()` function(without callback)?

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like that:

```
getPartners() {
  if (this.partners) {
    return Observable.of(this.partners);
  } else {
    return this._http.get('/app/partners/partners.data.json')
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError)
        .do(partners => {
          this.partners = partners;
        });
  }
}

getPartner(id:number):Observable<partner> {
  this.getPartners().map(partners => {
    return partners.find(partner => (partner.id == id));
  });
}
```

And execute the method this way:

```
this.service.getPartner('some id').subscribe(partner => {
  console.log(partner);
});
```

Comment: I like this a lot! But where will `this.partners` be assigned?

Comment: Thanks! Its work, but.... Here is my code [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/vLVW6VmYzvVIksEZIPyd?p=preview). Its work if it loaded from default route(PartnersPage). But if I reload page on url 'somesite.com/#/partner/1', then I receive error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in [{{partner.name}} in PartnerInfoDirective"

Comment: You're welcome! I think that it's because the data i's loaded asynchronously at the beginning. You should use the Elvis operator: "{{partner?.name}}".

Comment: Elvis operator not help.

Comment: Could you update your question with the content of the component where the error occurs? Thanks!

Comment: I update code [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/vLVW6VmYzvVIksEZIPyd?p=preview). When I add elvis operator, the error no longer occurs, but the data are not displayed on the page(app/partner.info.directive.html) if I reload page on url 'somesite.com/#/partner/1'

Comment: Your problem is because the template path isn't correct for the partner details component. See this working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/019KUADxCPWQl37dSWVi?p=preview.

Comment: You about `templateUrl: './app/partners.details.html'`? This not help.

Comment: What do you mean by "this not help"? The details screen is displayed in my case...

Comment: Its work fine if in app/partners.details.ts I initialize Partner `private partner:Partner = new Partner();` [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/vLVW6VmYzvVIksEZIPyd?p=preview). But I'm not sure that's right way.

Comment: Thierry, details page open's fine when you start app from default route `PartnersPage`. But if you go to '.../#/partner/1' and then reload page: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in [{{partner.name}} in PartnerInfoDirective"

Answer (score 1):

You could use `publishLast()` as well to capture the event.

```
constructor() {
  this.partners = this._http.get('/app/partners/partners.data.json')
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError)
        //shares the subscription with all observers so you don't get repeated
        //calls and caches the result.
        .publishLast();
  //Initiates the http call
  this.connection = this.partners.connect();
}

getPartner(id:number):Observable<partner> {

  return this.partners
             //Convert Observable<partner[]> to Observable<partner>
             .flatMap(x => x)
             .filter(p => p.id === id);
}
```

Comment: Its work to, but I get the same error(see description in my previous comment)

Comment: I would assume because you are trying to load Partner before the service has returned it. I am not familiar enough with Angular2 to tell you how to do an @Input asynchronously, but for Rx you should avoid "breaking" out of the Observable, in anything but trivial applications it will become a nightmare to track your system state. See my modification to your [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/r4r4IOv8qHC7GQnQBRWT?p=preview)